# Read .strings file in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I'm creating a Mac app and I want to localize my Labels. I thought a `.strings` file would be a better choice. But I have trouble reading `.strings` file in Objective-C. I'm looking for a simpler method.

This is my `.string` file content:

```
"LABEL_001" = "Start MyApp";
"LABEL_002" = "Stop MyApp";
"LABEL_003" = "My AppFolder";
...
```

I have already looked at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/LoadingResources/Strings/Strings.html.

This is my code:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *strFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Labels" ofType:@"strings"];
NSString *tt =NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"LABEL_001",strFilePath,bundle, nil);
NSLog(@"STRING ::: %@",tt);
```

But the string tt gives `"LABEL_001"`, I want `"Start MyApp"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at NSLocalizedString ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One. You have to name your file `Localizable.strings` in the `<LANGUAGENAME>.lproj` directory in the app bundle.

Two. Use the `NSLocalizedString` macro:

```
NSString *loc = NSLocalizedString(@"LABEL_001", nil);
```

Three. If nothing works, you can initialize an NSDictionary using a strings file, as a strings file is a special type of plist:

```
NSString *fname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"whatever" ofType:@"strings"];
NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:fname];
NSString *loc = [d objectForKey:@"LABEL_001"];
```

Comment: Swift4, the same idea, still helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Labels" ofType:@"strings"];
    NSData *plistData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSString *error; NSPropertyListFormat format;

    NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistData
                                                          mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListImmutable
                                                                    format:&format
                                                          errorDescription:&error];
    NSString *stringname = [dictionary objectForKey:@"LABEL_001"];
```

I think it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here the your code

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *strFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Labels" ofType:@"strings"];
NSString *tt =NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"LABEL_001",strFilePath,bundle, nil);
NSLog(@"STRING ::: %@",tt);
```

The problem here is the 2nd Param "strFilePath", change it to @"Labels" so the above code would become,

```
NSString *tt =NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"LABEL_001",@"Labels",bundle, nil);
```

For reference, the following line copied from Apple Docs regarding table name,
"When specifying a value for this parameter, include the filename without the .strings extension."

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple Code**

Just create a method as follows

```
- (void)localisationStrings
{
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"localisation" ofType:@"strings"];
    NSDictionary *localisationDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"\n %@",[localisationDict objectForKey:@"hello"]);
}
```