# Foreign language on ios devices

Tags: ios, string, localization

I have an IOS app which have a Mexican Localized strings file and I would know what's doing that the app is MX localized. There is no "Español (México)" in the Ipad language list...

Edit2:
I have set the language to "Español" and set the timezone to Mexico, but all the app stay configured as spanish app.
Can't we make a mexican localized app (or other localization profile that is using sub-identifier)?!

Saint clous very muche !

Answer (score 1):

You can choose Spanish - Mexico localization inside Other item of list.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options here:

Add in your project settings the language and "localize" the files.

[image]

Localize the single files (for example the `Localizable.strings`)

[image] - 
[image]

Or access it inside code with

```
NSString *localID = ((NSLocale *)[NSLocale currentLocale]).localeIdentifier;
```

for example and build up a different structure (like I had to do in "[Allow only specific translations for different schemes/targets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979168/allow-only-specific-translations-for-different-schemes-targets)" for example)

Comment: My app is already Localized, I have es-MX Localizable.
My probleme is that I can't test the Méxican version with Spanish language settings on Ipad because I have also a Spanish localizable file in my project.

Comment: Okay, I understand your problem. the `NSLocalizedString` seems not to take the **es_mx** identifier, even though it is set. In this case I really recommand to take a look at my link and **restruct the localization call** if you find no other way. But use this line given here instead of the one in the other answer, or will never get the _mx in the identifier :)

Comment: I think i expressed myself badly ^^.
In fact i don't know how the locale MX is set, because there is no "Español (México)" in the Ipad language list... I tryed to set the language as Español and set the timezone to Mexico but it did nothing. How the sub-identifier is set in the locale of the device ?
At final, I want to launch my app with a device that's have locale settings set to es-MX

Comment: this should be the right way, but it seems that it is not working. Therefor I have this "workaround" because you can get out of your region (`((NSLocale *)[NSLocale currentLocale]).localeIdentifier`) your desired identifier (**es_mx**). But you cannot use this with `NSLocalizedString` (as it seems), so you have to restruct and call the localized strings from bundle. Already took a look at the link? If you have questions we can go into chat instead of flooding the comments ;)

Comment: you need at least 20 reputation to gain write access :/ http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32687/geos-direct-help